# Getting data from a textblock (on a listbox) via a contextmenu click

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

as the title suggests i have a listbox with a contextmenu. I'm trying to get the value from an entry on the listbox via  a context menu. The code i currently have is as follows;

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#90361F" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#90361F" Width="488"> 
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu Tag="{Binding .}">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Click="MenuItemDelete_Click" Header="Delete Timer"/>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#90361F" Width="488" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding e2name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="25"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Tag="{Binding name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding datetime}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Now the contextmenu click event

```
private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var me = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag as ListBoxItem;

    }
```

i'm trying to get the value from the binding of name, i'm also using a tag to try and pass the data. as you can see from my click event, well it's pretty rubbish! From what i've read and understand i do need to make use of ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag but i'm not sure on how to init it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move the Tag attribute with relative binding on the MenuItem object instead of ContextMenu one?
Using the Tag to achieve your task is a pretty common use.

then the expression Tag="{Binding .}" binds to the tag the whole object binded on ListBoxItem, so probably your dynamic cast `as ListBoxItem` have to be changed in `as YourDataModelItem`

Answer (score 0):

In point of view, you have to try with binding with ContextMenu item than the whole context menu.

That is the Tag={Binding} should be from context Menu and should be added for each ContextMenu Item.

Modified Xaml is as follows .

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" Height="500" ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#90361F" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#90361F" Width="488"> 
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Click="MenuItemDelete_Click" Header="Delete Timer" Tag="{Binding}"/>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#90361F" Width="488" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding e2name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="25"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Tag="{Binding name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding datetime}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Also make sure that "ListBoxItem" is the list box item source's each item type. :)